# Batch variables dont give promt to set

Tags: loops, batch-file, variables

I'm brand new to batch file scripting, so this is going to make me appear stupid, but my variables in my test are not working.

Here is the cmd script:

```
@echo off
cls
: bruh
echo welcome to the shop, what would you like?
pause
set p/ grapes=
cls
echo oh so you want %grapes%?
pause
echo you have bought %grapes%
pause
cls 
goto bruh
```

Whenever I get to the variable, it just says press any key to continue.

Does anyone know how to fix this?

Comment: To begin with the command option is `/P` not `p/`. Please open a Command Prompt window, type `set /?`, press the `[ENTER]` key, and read its usage information. I would also advise, before you get bogged down with using that option, that you use an inventory/itemlist, to ensure that only items in that inventory can be selected too. Allowing the end user to type anything, _(or nothing)_, at the `set /p` prompt, needs proper validation code to prevent accidental or deliberate input.

Comment: `it just says press any key to continue.`: Yes. that's what `pause` is supposed to do. By the way: `set /p` is able to show a prompt: `set /p "grapes=What would you like? "`

Answer (score 0):

your set command was incorrect. its `set /p` **not** `set p/`.here's a working code

```
@echo off
cls
: bruh
set input=
set /p input=echo welcome to the shop, what would you like?
cls
echo oh so you want %input%?
pause
echo you have bought %input%
pause
cls 
goto bruh
```

Thanks to @Compo he reminded me to clear content of %input%

Comment: Justaus3r, you should clear the content of `%input%` preferably on the line above your `set /p` command as it is looping, and will still have the last loops content at the next propting_, (I've already explained that to you under one of your other answers just in the last half hour or so)_. BlazedRasta, please note my comment under the main question, your and this code does not prevent me from inputting nothing, malicious code, or just deliberately wrong input.

Comment: @Compo i don't know,maybe he just named variable as grapes intentionally.he didn't mention that he needs condition in his script to compare his input.Btw BlazedRasta Compo is right this code won't prevent you from typing wrong input if you want the input to be grapes only...........

Comment: The point I was making to you was if the end user inputs `grapes` as their item the first time, and next time accidentally hits enter, before typing `milk`, the code would run using `grapes` again, which I'm sure would not be wanted, or could, depending upon the rest of the code, cause issues elsewhere.

Comment: @Compo oh yeah that's why i cleared the input when you pointed that out.the code is updated now